# How do I host a website (parts of it) on Nginx and Apache at the same time

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, hosting, vps

I am looking to run my main website on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and [www.example.com/page](http://www.example.com/page) on nginx (React/Next.js) and the blog on [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) on Apache (wordpress).

Is this possible ?

I am using a VPS

I want the ip address to remain the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

- You can configure an apache or nginx server that can be reached from the public and with a proxyPass configuration you can serve other content (based on path and or domain) from another server (running apache or ngix or what you prefer)
- You can configure a loadBalancer, such as HAProxy, and direct request to a specific backed (apache, nginx or whatever you prefer) according to the URL/domain requested.